# "index N is out of bounds for axis 0 with size N" when running Parallel KMeans whereas sequential KMeans works fine

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm trying to run KMeans using scikit-learn implementation in parallel, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_kmeans.py", line 114, in <module>
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2048, n_jobs=-1).fit(descriptors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 889, in fit
    return_n_iter=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 362, in k_means
    for seed in seeds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 768, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 719, in retrieve
    raise exception
sklearn.externals.joblib.my_exceptions.JoblibIndexError: JoblibIndexError
_________________________________________________________________________
Multiprocessing exception:
..........................................................................
IndexError: index 11683 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 11683
```

When I run KMeans with `n_jobs=1`, i.e. in as sequential manner, I get no errors and everything works just fine. But with `n_jobs=-1` I keep getting the error.

Here's the code I use:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2048, n_jobs=-1).fit(descriptors)
```

`descriptors` is a numpy array with shape `(11683, 128)`.

---

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in KMeans implementation?

What should I do about it (e.g. use `BiniBatchKMeans` etc)?

PS: I'm running it on the Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit machine with 4 Gb of RAM and Intel Core i7-4700HQ 2.40GHz

Comment: could you provide a __reproducible__ example?

Comment: what is your sklearn version?

Comment: @MaxU my sklearn version is 0.18.1. The thing is that the error I get appears from time to time, I'm not sure it's very reproducible. I was getting it for about 6 times in a row and decided to ask a question on SO. But now when I try the code, the error stopped appearing. For some reason, it seems to me like more of a hardware issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by converting the input data to float64, as descriptors.astype(np.float64).

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8583